# sidekiq + carrierwave + minimagick

Tags: carrierwave, sidekiq, minimagick

We're running a sidekiq job that does some carrierwave processing of some images.

Our our sidekiq box when running as the ubuntu user the job seems to do it's thing.
However when running under monit the job will fail with this error coming out of minimagick:

*Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: Command ("mogrify -format jpg -alpha remove -quality 85 /tmp/mini_magick20140711-31558-7ew026.png[0]") failed: {:status_code=>1, :output=>"mogrify: UnrecognizedAlphaChannelType `remove' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/3820.\n"}*

Same images being processed, same directories where the cached images are being put, really have no idea what's going on. Why would it work outside of monit but not within it?

Ubuntu 12.04
mogrify version 6.8.9-3

Comment: Not sure this is a programming question. Perhaps it would be on-topic for Super User or Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: that's really helpful. thanks. i figured it out. there were two versions of mogrify installed. the order of the directories in the PATH was likely different and it was picking up the wrong version.